# Better Code in LinQ?

Tags: c#, linq

```
string test = "asdf";

IEnumerable<char> str = test.ToArray().Distinct();

string[] strArray = str.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

I need to convert it to Enumerable and then I can make it into a string[].

Do you know a better solution about how to make it to string[] based on the variable test without using IEnumerable?

This current code above is a detour and I wonder if it possible to make it better with shortcut?

Comment: Your example is not clear. You want something like "aaab" to be transformed into the string array { "a", "b" } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
string[] strArry = test.Distinct().Select(x=> x.ToString()).ToArray();
```

There is no need to call `ToArray` in the first line, as string is already `IEnumerable<char>`.

> Do you know a better solution about how to make it to string[] based
>   on the variable test without using IEnumerable?

When you use `Distinct` it returns `IEnumerable<T>`, I am not sure what exactly you meant by avoiding `IEnumerable<T>` but you can also iterate through the characters in the string and convert them to string, without using LINQ.

Comment: Thank you for your help!